# trouble with output of recursive function

Tags: recursion

i'm having trouble getting the correct output of the function. The function output should show the expression. For example, if the input is "1234", then the output should be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10.

i can get the function to output the first part of the expression, but i'm not sure how to get it to output the sum as well.

heres what  i have so far:

```
void sumDigits(int num, int &sum){
sum += num % 10;

if(num < 10)
    cout << num;
else {
    sumDigits(num/10, sum);
    cout << " + " << num % 10;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do it in caller? 
you could pass the remaining digits number to process to a function and output sum when it's 0, but I doing it in the caller is better..

Answer (score 0):

`<<` can be chained. Try

```
cout << " + " << num % 10 << " = " << sum << endl;
```